# UITableView data source partly used array

Tags: ios, uitableview, datasource

I have a `UITableView` and an array for data source of it.
But I don't want to use all objects in the array but some of them.
since I need that array fully later, I don't want  neither remove any objects from array nor filter the array with the desired objects.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You need another array containing the data you want in the table.

Comment: what about the memory cost ?

Comment: What cost? An array is cheap. It will simply have references to the same objects in the original array.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to have two arrays:

1- All items are stored in original array;
2- Second array with indices of the items to show in the table

```
arrOne[arrSecond[i]]
```

would be the item number i in the table

Answer (score 0):

You need another array with the list of filtered items.